# Redirect single product pages to home in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, product

In this e-commerce, its not necessary a single product page, is there a way to redirect these links to my homepage?

I have 3 products pages, /individual-box, /quarterly-box, /semester-box.

I tried something like this:

```
function redirect_to_home() {
  if(!is_admin() && is_page('/product')) {
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_home');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'product_redirection_to_home', 100 );
function product_redirection_to_home() {
    if ( ! is_product() ) return; // Only for single product pages.

    wp_redirect( home_url() ); // redirect home.
    exit();
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).